# Are there any smart/standard ways of getting sidebar columns the same height with multiple widgets inside?

Tags: sidebar

JavaScript/jQuery works when there is an equal amount of widgets in each column/sidebar, checking the parent for height and applying that. I guess it's the styling of the widgets area that affects this.

Using flexbox they align horizontally according to size (see picture 2).

I realize this questions is about CSS, but I figure this is a common WordPress specific problem one can face because of the use of widgets.
[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't set align-items property it should be 'stretch' as default. You must have margin: auto on your columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox, just be sure to use `align-items: stretch` on the container. (From the looks, you currently have `align-items: center`.) For more info, I usually check the [CSS-Tricks article on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).